# How to generate self signed certificate with custom validity

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Trying to generate self signed certificates with online sites and with openssl. But every certificate is getting created with validity starting from today.

I need certificate whose validity starts from next year. As of now, it shud be "not-yet-valid".

How to define custom dates while generating certificate ?